# How to intercept return value of a gmock action

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am testing a class that has a factory. The factory is mocked using google mock. I used action and WillByDefault() to enable the mocked factory to construct example objects and return pointers to them. In the test I ask my class to create an object using the mocked factory and to return pointer to crated object. I want to make sure pointer returned from class is the same as pointer returned by mocked factory to the class.

Lets say I have a class dog, a dog factory and a kennel that uses the factory.

```
class dog;

class dogFactory{
    dog* makeDog() { return new dog; }
}

ACTION(makeDogInMock){ return new dog; }

class factoryMock : public factory{
    MOCK_METHOD1(makeDog, dog*());
}

class kennel{
    public:
    dog* dogInKennel;
    dogFactory factory;

    void putDogInKennel(){
        this->dogInKennel = factory.makeDog();
    }

    dog* getDogInKennel(){
        return this->dogInKennel;
    }

}
```

Then in test constructor I use the action as default operation:

```
ON_CALL(factoryMock, dog(_)).WillByDefault(makeDogInMock)
```

In test I want to know whether the kennel returns the same pointer as the `dogFactory` returned when called in `putDogInKennel()`, but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Do you HAVE to use actions? you could have your mock return a dog pointer living on the stack using `Return()`, and then check against that: `ON_CALL(factoryMock, dog(_)).WillByDefault(Return(dog_on_stack))`

Comment: No, I don't have to use them. Thank you, this simple solution just didn't appear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example it will never be the dog you specified in the default action, because the design of your system is incorrect (if you want to test it with the factory mock of course). Inside your system (`kennel`) you shouldn't keep the concrete factory object, but the pointer to the factory interface. This is called Dependency Injection. Your example might be modified in the following way:

```
class Dog{};

class IDogFactory {
public:
    virtual ~IDogFactory() = default;
    virtual Dog* makeDog() = 0;
};

class DogFactory: public IDogFactory {
public:
    ~DogFactory() override = default;
    Dog* makeDog() override {
        return new Dog;
    }
};

class DogFactoryMock: public IDogFactory {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(makeDog, Dog*());
};

class Kennel {
public:
    explicit Kennel(IDogFactory* factory): factory_(factory) {}
    void putDogInKennel(){
        dogInKennel_ = factory_->makeDog();
    }
    Dog* getDogInKennel(){
        return dogInKennel_;
    }
private:
    Dog* dogInKennel_;
    IDogFactory* factory_;
};

using testing::Return;

TEST(xxx, yyy) {
    Dog d;
    DogFactoryMock factoryMock;
    ON_CALL(factoryMock, makeDog()).WillByDefault(Return(&d));
    Kennel sut(&factoryMock);
    sut.putDogInKennel();
    Dog* dPtr = sut.getDogInKennel();
    std::cout << (dPtr == &d) << std::endl;  // outputs "true"
}
```

`IDogFactory` is the interface to the factory that is able to create the object of `Dog`. How exactly this `Dog` creation is done depends on the factory implementation, but your system does not depend on it. So, in the production you might create your `Kennel` passing the pointer to `DogFactory`, while in testing you can pass a pointer to `DogFactoryMock`. In the example I used raw pointers to objects on the stack, but I recommend using `std::shared_ptr` instead. Both for the return type from the factory and for the factory pointer inside your system.

Comment: You are right. In trying to simplify the problem, I oversimplified. In my real-life program I use Dependency Injection. Thank you for clear explanation and offering solution to my problem.